# Adding onChange logic to third-party react-day-picker element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-day-picker, react-final-form

I'm trying to integrate `react-day-picker`'s `DayPicker` with [`react-final-form`](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form).

React Final Form requires the use of a [`Field`](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#field--reactcomponenttypefieldprops) for each form field, which means creating an adapter component whenever you want to a third-party form element to be usable within the form. The adapter component [has to accept an `input` object containing `value` and `onChange`](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1221#issuecomment-229002540). The advice is [just to provide a new `onChange`](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1797#issuecomment-247798860).

[This approach, which works for many other components, doesn't work for `DayPicker`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640196/how-to-make-react-day-picker-compatible-with-redux-form). It seems like the issue is that [`DayPicker` doesn't actually have an `onChange`](http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPicker) method, so it's up to us to manage what happens when the calendar changes and then store the dates in `value` property that `react-final-form` expects.

I've created a codepen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/pcraig3/date-picker-sandbox

I have a `handleDayClick` method in `Calendar.js` which runs when days are clicked, but `onChange` isn't being triggered for the calendar consistently.

- `selectedDays` is being updated immediately within the `Calendar` itself, but the `Form` is not getting the correct dates until the calendar is unfocused
- The form's `validate` method is only being called once (the first time selecting a day), whereas it is called each time the native text input value is updated.

I would like the form values to be synced up with the calendar's external state and for the validate method to be triggered each time a day is clicked/unclicked. Is this possible to achieve or am I doing completely the wrong thing?

Answer (score 4):

It's probably easier to use the `<DayPickerInput>` component, instead. That component uses a standard HTML input, which supports `onChange`. I did it like this:

```js
<Field name={id}>
  {({ input, meta }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label htmlFor={id}>Date: </label>
      <DayPickerInput
        {...input}
        onDayChange={day => input.onChange(day)}
        inputProps={{ id: id }}
      />
      {meta.error && meta.touched && <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>}
    </React.Fragment>
  )}
</Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can add the logic to the "inputProps" prop, since this takes in props to the input component, you can also add css to it as well.

> **inputProps Object**
>   : Additional props to add to the input component.

Your code will look like this:

```js
const dateChanged = day => (console.log(day)); //function to call when date changes

inputProps={{
  style: styles.dayPickerInput,
  onChange: event => dateChanged(event.target.value),
}}
```

If you use onDayChange alone, it'll fire after the user "clicks" to select a day, not when the user actually types a date inside the input field, using this extra onchange listener will be a safeguard for you, if the input field is enabled for users to type in the date, which they might.